# Find if an item is in an array and exclude it from select options with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have two scopes (arrays). One with room data and one with room list.
So everytime a user want to add some data for each room have to select it from a dropdown (select option) and add that data he wants.
Now, i need to exclude every room tat already have some data from the dropdown and i am trying like thi.

Here is the Room list:

```
$scope.propertyRooms = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Room 1 Sea View"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "Room 2 Mountain View"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "Room 3"
    }

];
```

Here is the room with data (to exclude):

```
$scope.ratePlansRoomsSettings = [
            {
                id: "1",
                name: "Room 1 Sea View",
                allotment: "10",
                minPax: "1",
                maxPax: "5",
                maxAdult: "5",
                maxChild: "4",
                maxInf: "1",
                childAllowed: true
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                name: "Room 2 Mountain View",
                allotment: "10",
                minPax: "1",
                maxPax: "10",
                maxAdult: "10",
                maxChild: "8",
                maxInf: "1",
                childAllowed: false
            }
        ];
```

Here is how i am trying to exclude the selected:

```
$scope.getAvailableRooms = function(){
    var selectedRooms = [];

    for(i = 0; i < $scope.propertyRooms.length; i++){
        var found = false;
        for(j = 0; j < $scope.ratePlansRoomsSettings.length; j++){
            if($scope.ratePlansRoomsSettings[j].id == $scope.propertyRooms[i].id){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            selectedRooms.push($scope.propertyRooms[i]);
        }
        return $scope.propertyRooms;

    }

}
```

here is the select options:

```
<select ng-model="room.name" ng-options="p.name as p.name for p in getAvailableRooms()" ng-hide="room.name" class="form-control"></select>
```

The problem is that the select options give me all the time all the rooms from the propertyRooms scope instead those only that are not selected.

I am not receiving any errors but i beleive i am wrong in the for function.

Comment: shouldnt you return `selectedRooms` instead of the unfiltered `$scope.propertyRooms` ?

Comment: @Jeyp I have tried that but i am getting an empty option. even in the console.log it's empty.

Comment: Also, shouldnt the return be after the loop, it is currently IN the loop, isn't it?

Comment: omg yes, that's it i feel so noob :P

Comment: Hehe, I think every developer once had a problem like this :P However, have you though of writing a filter for this purpose?

Comment: Hmmm, i am not sure how :P

Comment: I'll try to add a suggestion to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$scope.getAvailableRooms = function(){
    var selectedRooms = [];

    for(i = 0; i < $scope.propertyRooms.length; i++){
        var found = false;
        for(j = 0; j < $scope.ratePlansRoomsSettings.length; j++){
            if($scope.ratePlansRoomsSettings[j].id == $scope.propertyRooms[i].id){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            selectedRooms.push($scope.propertyRooms[i]);
        }
    }
    return selectedRooms;
}
```

However, have you considered using a filter for this purpose? You could write your custom filter as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). Just an example here:

```
.filter('rooms', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var selectedRooms = [];

      for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
          var found = false;
          for(j = 0; j < $scope.ratePlansRoomsSettings.length; j++){
              if($scope.ratePlansRoomsSettings[j].id == input[i].id){
                  found = true;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if(!found){
              selectedRooms.push(input[i]);
          }
      }
      return selectedRooms;
    };
  })
```

Comment: That was it thank you! Regarding the filters it is not what i want to do but anyway the answer was what i did wrong ;) :P